# celery[sqs] way to get publish confirmation

Tags: python, flask, celery, amazon-sqs

I am running Flask and Celery to handle some long-running tasks. In code I have something like :

```py
@app.route('/mappings/v1/hello')
def hello_world():
    task_id = add_together.delay(1,2)
    LOGGER.info("Hello World! {}".format(task_id))
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I can see in logger that task_id was printed and subitted.

```
2020-05-01 10:53:04,178 - [140481776820552] - [DummyThread-49797] - app - INFO - Hello World! 644d207d-d806-419b-a56f-dadb707cb9ab
```

Celery is already running as a daemon in other Kubernetes pods. However, I never saw that the task_id mentioned above was picked by a celery worker. So looking to find a way that allows me to get some acknowledgment from SQS. **I am suspecting that message was never published to SQS.**

Something like `published_confirm` that we have for RabbitMQ. Any help will be appreciated.